Pyphi Package For Python 3.8 and Later
How can I deploy PyPhi package version 1.2.0 with Python 3.8 or later for integrated information research? Is there a newer version of PyPhi available beyond 1.2.0?
I'm working on integrated information theory, and I intend to utilize the PyPhi package. However, it appears that the latest version, 1.2.0, is only compatible with Python versions up to 3.7. Can someone advise me on how to deploy PyPhi version 1.2.0 with Python 3.8 or later for my research? Additionally, I'm curious if there has been any release of a newer version of PyPhi beyond 1.2.0 that might offer compatibility with Python 3,.8, or later.

Have you tried using PyPhi with Python 3.8? What errors do you get trying to use it?

Yes, I tried it! Actually, I am using Spyder as an IDE, and I faced 2 problems: First, When I installed Python version 3.7 in a new environment, I faced an Error with the Kernel of Spyder (Python 3.7 did not support by Spyder 5.4). Second, I tried to use Python 3.8, however, it seems that the Pyphi functions cannot run properly.

When you say Pyphi functions cannot run properly what is the exact behavior you are observing? What is the expected behavior? Do you have some specific code that others can use to reproduce the problem? Please edit and update your question with those details :-)

Yes, Let me give an example. when I used this code :subsystem_cause = pyphi.Subsystem(network, state, nodes=node_indices, backward_tpm=True) which is recommended by link, I observed the following Error: TypeError: init() got an unexpected keyword argument 'backward_tpm'. The same Error has occurred when I used the following common code: sia = pyphi.backwards.sia(subsystem_cause, subsystem_effect) AttributeError: module 'pyphi' has no attribute 'backwards'!!!
